# Saving react+redux application state to *server* using redux-persist?

Tags: reactjs, persistence, redux

I am using [redux-persist](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist) to persist the state of my react+redux application to the local storage (on the client, then). So far so good.

However, I wonder if it would be possible to have a custom persistor to read/write my app state on the server instead of local storage ?

It sounds a bit crazy, but I find it would be a good (and cheap in term of coding effort) way to share the state of an application between multiple clients, or to ensure my server and my app stay in sync...

It seems it is as easy as this (pseudo code ahead !):

```
import {persistStore, autoRehydrate, createPersistor} from 'redux-persist'

class remoteStorage {
    setItem(key, value) {
        // send key and value to server
    }

    getItem(key) {
        // return value for key from server
    }

    removeItem(key) {
       // remove key from server 
    }

    getAllKeys() {
        // get keys from server
    }
}

...

this.customPersistor = createPersistor(store, { storage: new remoteStorage() });

...
```

Does someone has experience with this kind of technique ?

Is it a good idea ?

I am worried about possible performance problems in case of a lot of updates.

Are there alternatives to achieve the same doing/using something else ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This seems perfectly fine to me. Performance isn't natively bad, just depends on what you're doing. Imagine an FPS where tons of stuff happens all the time that needs to get shared between many players. You may want to debounce / throttle updates to some reasonable delay. Another thing to consider is that if you're persisting state on the server, localstorage may be unnecessary.